# Why do my links show syntax errors in Razor MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using links like this within my Razor MVC3 files:

```
<a href="/Weather/">
<a href="/Entertainment/">
```

But the links all show the following message:

```
File /Weather/ was not found
File /Entertainment/ was not found
```

Is there something wrong with the way that I am specifying the link. The links are valid and the code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're linking to other controller actions, you should use the `Html.ActionLink` method

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx)